# how can I sort records based on a calculation Rails

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a field in my database table called reputation.

It contains  a hash.

E`xample: {:kout => 20, :google => 40 } etc...`

When I get the records I want to sort them based upon a calculation performed with the values in that hash attribute.

I'm a NOOB and have no idea how to do this.

Any ideas welcome.

Rails 3.2

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622206/ruby-how-to-pass-a-custom-comparator-to-sort

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

open console and try this

```
h = {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>150}
1.9.3p125 :023 > h.values.sort
=> [100, 150, 200] 
1.9.3p125 :024 > h.keys.sort
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```